# $P(A \cap \bar{B})$ equals $P(\bar{A} \cap B)$

Tags: probability

I have to prove that $P(A \cap \bar{B})$ equals $P(\bar{A} \cap B)$. P-means the probability of an event.

So in words first one should be as follows:
Probability that event A happens and not event B and the second one is that event B happens and not event A.

How would I do it?

Comment: I don't think the proposition is true.

Comment: For example, if $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then $P(A \cap \bar{B})=P(A) (1-P(B))=P(A)-P(A)P(B)\neq P(B)-P(A)P(B)=P(\bar{A} \cap B)$.

Comment: not true.${}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not true in general. For example, let $A$ be the probability of rolling an even number on a die. Let $B$ be the probability of rolling a $1$ on a die.

Then $P(A \cap \bar{B}) = 1/2$, but $P(\bar{A} \cap B) = 1/6$.

Comment: so that's why I did'nt find a way how to prove it... did'nt even think about the possibility of not being true. Thanks!